# I've subscribed to an item on Steam Workshop - how do I download it?

Tags: steam

Now that the Portal 2 Perpetual Testing Initiative is out, I've been looking at some of the available maps, but I'm not sure how to actually download them.

I've gone into an author's or collection's page, where I can subscribe to an item. I've clicked the Subscribe button and the subscriptions have been added successfully, but nothing else happens - no downloads begin, no download buttons appear.

How do I actually download the maps I've subscribed to? I hope it doesn't involve going into the actual Portal 2 game, as it's a bit of an inconvenience to have to start it up just to download the maps.

N.B. I've left the Portal 2 tag out because I assume all Steam workshop pages work in the same way, and answers will apply to other games as well.

Comment: Maaan why isn't there a badge for getting >10k views and only 1 upvote? :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not do anything. The content should download automatically. In the case of Portal 2, the map will download when you try to start it for the first time

Comment: Hmm, so there's no way to pre-load a map? Disappointing :/

Comment: @Alex - The map files are not very big what is there to "pre-download" exactly?

Comment: @Ramhound well, they may not be big, but if I just subscribed to 20-30 maps (which I have) and I know I'm not going to be able to play immediately, I'd much rather have them download in the background to be ready when I can play. Steam will download games in the background, even very small ones, so I assumed the Workshop files would be similarly handled.

Comment: Finally got the chance to test this and realised what you guys meant. Didn't take long to load the levels at all! Happy me :)

Comment: @Ramhound What's "very big" or not is all relative. It seems to me that most maps are > 5MB. And unfortunately in this country of terrible internet access, that means a few minutes per map to download. If that means I make a cup of coffee while the first downloads, then others download while I'm solving those that have already been downloaded - it won't be a problem.